# How to use the latest openssl update?

Tags: c++, openssl

I have openssl 0.9.8g installed on my computer...
It seems that it has a known bug which I ran into.

I wanted to install the current version 1.0.0d which seems to have fixed the bug.

so, basic install :

```
$ ./config
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

However even after recompiled my software I still get the same error, and it is for sure coming from 0.9.8 since it is written in the error :

> error:1408F06B:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:bad
>   decompression:/SourceCache/**OpenSSL098**/OpenSSL098-35/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:438:

Comment: Is whatever app producing that app statically linked? Or perhaps it's specifically requesting the 0.9.8 .so's.

Comment: Not that I know of, just using -lssl flag while compiling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you installed your downloaded version of OpenSSL to `/home/yourname/openssl`. Then you need to tell your software to use that custom install instead of the pre-packaged 0.9.8 that already resides on your file system. There's no need to uninstall that, you can have several installations on your machine. "Telling" your software where to find your custom installation is by providing the linker with the correct paths where to find libssl and libcrypto. Add these to the linking options in your Makefile:

```
-L/home/yourname/openssl/lib -Wl,-R/home/yourname/openssl/lib
```

Then it should link against the new version just fine. To verify it did, you can use

```
ldd <your_executable_or_library>
```

and verify that the custom OpenSSL path is listed there and not the old one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the OS you are using, but my guess is that you first have to remove the erroneous old version before you move on the install the newer one. Some OSes don't put libraries installed with `sudo make install` in the same place as with a packet manager. Also the lookup order of the libraries might cause it to load the older one.

Comment: using debian sarge... I'll try that but, How do I uninstall previous version of openssl ?

Comment: nope, I have installed openssl from the source code downloaded from their website... not apt-get (needed the latest version at that time too)